# When to use server vs. client side helpers?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

There are server controls here

http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/

But then there are jquery controls as well.

Can anyone tell me which way to go ? Id rather just go all one way or all the other.. Seems like the way to do MVC is to avoid having server side code have anything to do with creating controls (htmlhelpers?) like webforms. I think you want just want it to server up data through jquery ajax posts right?

So I am trying to understand the basics of setting up that style project.. any simple examples ? I wish there was a simple MVC site that covered doing the basics in the most current modern way.. I have the MVC music store example.. I have MVC nerd dinner example..

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making an incorrect assumption.

MVC HTML helpers generate code based on the properties of a view model (and/or from anything you want). While this assists in the model binding process (thus loosely coupling it to a server action), it's quite different from creating web forms server controls:

- full control over markup
- no fake event model on top of HTTP
- no heavy state management
- view model should provide complete abstraction between controller and view markup
- little or no server logic is connected to the inputs generated by a helper

The correct question for determining server versus client is whether or not it fits the application requirements (which include whether or not you require JavaScript). Applications which desire/require a highly responsive experience are often more client-heavy.